# Pass table to button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A table is generated with PHP. The division of the table should be retained as far as possible. The table should be passed as in the example with selectable options.

```js
$(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").text($(this).text());
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").val($(this).text());

   });

});

 $(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").text($(this).text());
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").val($(this).text());
   });

});
```

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");


li i {display:none}

table {float:left}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span> </button>
  <button class="btn">Please Select From List</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a href="#" class="" data-value=1>
      <p><span> Option I</span></p>
      </a> </li>
    <li>
    <li><a href="#" class="" data-value=2>
      <p><span> Option II  <i class="bi bi-info-square-fill"></i></span></p>
      </a> </li>
    <li>
    <li>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Option III</strong></td>
            <td align="right"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="bi bi-info-square-fill"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have prepared an example how it should look like. So far, however, only text is transferred. If possible, the entire table including images should be displayed.

> Option I is the basis for selectable options.
>
> Option II is the current view with icon. That would be an emergency
> solution if no table can be passed.
>
> Option III is the current representation with the pass table with no
> selectable option.

other suggestions are welcome

Comment: Have you tried this? `$(".dropdown-menu li a,.dropdown-menu li table")`

Comment: Picking up on *"only text is transferred"* - that's because you're using `$(..).text($(..).text())` use html() instead `$(..).html($(..).html())`

Comment: Unclear what you mean by, or want to, when you state *"pass table to button"* - you really don't want an entire `<table>` inside a `<button>` - but that's not what your code is currently attempting.

Comment: yes exactly so far I only pass text with javascript. however, the entire table content should appear in the button

Comment: it works with `$(..).html($(..).html())` how it's supposed to be. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

instead of the link, the entire table was now passed as an option. now the entire table can be selected as an option.

```js
$(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu li table").click(function(){

      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").html($(this).html());
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").val($(this).html());

   });

});

 $(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li table', function(){
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").html($(this).html());
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").val($(this).html());
   });

});
```

in full it looks like this

```js
$(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu li table").click(function(){

      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").html($(this).html());
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").val($(this).html());

   });

});

 $(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li table', function(){
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").html($(this).html());
      $(".btn:nth-child(2n)").val($(this).html());
   });

});
```

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");


li i {display:none}

table {float:left}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span> </button>
  <button class="btn">Please Select From List</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Option I</strong></td>
            <td align="right"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="bi bi-info-square-fill"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </li>
    <li>
    <li>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Option II</strong></td>
            <td align="right"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="bi bi-info-square-fill"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </li>
    <li>
    <li>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Option III</strong></td>
            <td align="right"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="bi bi-info-square-fill"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).